# I need help ordering columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: css

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so forgive me if I make mistakes.
    Would like to reverse these 2 columns in bootstrap and it doesn't work. Tried with order-2 but no luck.

```
 <div class="flexbox">
  <div class="container list">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Customers</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 order-2">
        <div class="list-group" id="supplier-list">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 order-">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">Name</div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="supplier-name" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">CUI</div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="supplier-cui" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">ID</div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="supplier-id" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example">
          </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="suppliers-update" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        <button type="button" id="suppliers-delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a wrong class:- ``col-sm-6 order-``. It should be ``col-sm-6 order-1``

Comment: @Alin _ the 'order-' class in your second column is incomplete